# React-Native packager stops after "Building Dependency Graph"

Tags: xcode, react-native, macos-sierra

React-Native packager stops after `Building Dependency Graph` when I'm trying to run my app on a device (iPhone) in my regular home wifi network. The console says `__nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke` and `Connection has no connected handler` and I can't use any of the reload features on the device.

If I set up a wifi network on my Mac and connect my iPhone directly, it works as it should:

```
[18:26:09] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (1542ms)
[18:26:38] <START> request:/index.ios.bundle
platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false
...
```

I'm using XCode 8, macOS Sierra GM on a 2014 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a live and ongoing issue here on GitHub that may help you out https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10027